# How do I select GTK icon theme?

Tags: lubuntu, gtk

I run Lubuntu 13.10 with the window manager Blackbox. I have set the GTK theme to Lubuntu-default in settings.ini:

```
$ cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini 
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Lubuntu-default
```

This makes GTK3 applications use the Box icon theme; in GPicView, for instance, the toolbar icons look like this:

[image]

In Gedit, however, the toolbar icons look like this:

[image]

How do I make Gedit use the Box icon theme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `gtk-icon-theme-name` to `lubuntu` in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` (for GTK 2 applications) and in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (for GTK 3 applications). Here is the content of my GTK config files:

```
$ cat ~/.gtkrc-2.0 
include "/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 10"
gtk-icon-theme-name = "lubuntu"

$ cat ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini 
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Lubuntu-default
gtk-icon-theme-name = lubuntu
```

In `/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` the property `gtk-icon-theme-name` is set to `Lubuntu` (capitalized) which must be a bug because there is no such icon theme installed on my system.