# Preserving GTK theme with gksudo

Tags: lubuntu, gtk, gksudo

I have a computer with two (non simultaneous) users who are both in the `sudo` group. Is there a way to preserve the user's GTK theme with `gksudo`, for instance when running the update manager? By default the Raleigh theme is used.

I use Lubuntu 14.04 with a simple window manager (Blackbox) and no display manager.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why applications launched through `gksudo` aren't using your user's theme. It works for me on a full Lubuntu system. (But that uses Openbox, not Blackbox.) Fortunately:

- The best solution for a program like the Update Manager is probably to install polkit (which is normally present) and run the Update Manager *without* `gksudo`. (See **Way 1** below.)
- For applications that do have to be started as root, or if you don't want polkit installed, a workaround is to [specify the theme you want with `GTK_THEME`](http://worldofgnome.org/running-gtk-applications-different-themes-per-app/) (see **Way 2** and **Way 3**).

### Way 1: Install polkit (a.k.a. PolicyKit).

The best solution for utilities like:

- Software Updater / Update Manager (`update-manager`)
- Ubuntu Software Center (`software-center`)
- Lubuntu Software Center (`lubuntu-software-center`)
- Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`)

...and many of the other system administration utilities in Ubuntu, is to **just not run them as root at all.**

Normally you don't need to run these utilities as root because they integrate with [**polkit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) and use it (instead of `sudo`) to perform authentication (just) when neccessary. Since the program showing you the user interface actually runs as you and not as root, it displays in accordance with your user account's configuration.

Typically nothing special must be done to achieve this, even on a Lubuntu system. Ubuntu is designed so that these utilities can just be run as a non-root user, without any special configuration.

But **since your system is especially minimal, you probably don't have polkit installed.** You can get it by installing the [policykit-1 [image: Install policykit-1]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/policykit-1) and [policykit-1-gnome [image: Install policykit-1-gnome]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/policykit-1-gnome) packages.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install policykit-1 policykit1-1-gnome
```

With polkit installed, these utlities should automatically use it and won't need to be launched as root.

However, this may not be suitable:

- if you don't want to install polkit, *or*
- for running GTK+ programs as root that *haven't* been written to use polkit (such as Leafpad or Gedit).

### Way 2: Set the desired GTK+ theme when you run `gksudo`.

Suppose you wish to run *`gedit`* as root. Note that this technique works the same way for other GTK+ programs (such as the Update Manager).

Instead of running `gksudo gedit`, you can run:

```
gksudo env GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit
```

Replace **`HighContrast`** with the name of the desired theme.

<sup>(I use [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/env.1.html) because although `sudo` supports `sudo VARIABLE=name command` syntax, `gksu`/`gksudo` does not.)</sup>

### Way 3: Make a launcher that that sets the desired theme.

This is the same as Way 2, just running your program through a launcher rather than typing a command each time.

[To make a shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466395/how-can-i-create-a-quick-launcher-in-lubuntu/466515#466515) to run a program (like *`gedit`*) with a particular GTK+ theme (like **`HighContrast`**) as root in LXDE, run:

```
lxshortcut -o ~/Desktop/'gedit (as root)'
```

In place of ***`gedit (as root)`***, put whatever you want as the launcher's display name.

In the File Properties window that comes up when you run that command, click the Desktop Entry tab. In the text box labeled command, put:

```
gksudo env GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit
```

You can leave everything else blank and just click OK.

If you want, you can use the full paths of the executables being run (`/usr/bin/gksudo` and, in this example, `/usr/bin/gedit`.) But this is not generally necessary.

[image]
<sup>*Making a launcher for `gksudo env GTK_THEME HighContrast gedit`. (The left part of the command is not visible.)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually, I have `policykit-1` and `policykit1-1-gnome` installed but when I launch update-manager (as non-root) it is first checking for updates and then a dialog pops up saying "You are not allowed to perform this action".

Comment: When I run `gksudo env GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit` Gedit still uses the Raleigh theme although I have HighContrast in `/usr/share/themes/`. Setting the theme in `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` works. Maybe something is incompletely configured.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Does `GTK_THEME` work at all on your system--that is, even without `gksudo`? That is, suppose your user's configured theme is something other than `HighContrast` (so, when you just run `gedit`, it runs with some other theme). Does `GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit` work to make it run with the `HighContrast` theme? (You don't need the `env` when leaving off `gksudo`, though it should work the same with and without the leading `env`.)

Comment: The command `GTK_THEME=HighContrast gedit` launches Gedit with the user's GTK theme, i.e. setting GTK_THEME has no effect.

Comment: If I understand [your comment](http://askubuntu.com/q/517539#comment704017_517849), you've set your theme [in the way you described here](http://askubuntu.com/a/452206). Interestingly, I tried that on a "regular" Lubuntu system (using openbox instead of blackbox) and it *didn't* change the theme for me (but setting `GTK_THEME` does work for me with openbox). ...What happens if you [create those config files](http://askubuntu.com/a/452206) for the root user, then try `gksudo` again? For example, for GTK+3, `/root/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (`/root` = root's home dir) with the desired config.

Comment: Yes, I have set the theme as described on the page you linked to. It's strange that it doesn't work for you in Openbox. Setting GTK+3 theme for root (as you describe) works.

Answer (score 0):

I actually have the same problem as I use i3wm. I suppose since you are using Lubuntu, you should have lxappearance installed. Run that with gksudo, then you should see your theme for gksudo selected. Change and apply that, you should have the theme desired for the gksudo.